# INSERT in a remote server is far too slow, how to speed it up?

Tags: mysql, insert, remote

I need to load 480.000 rows into a remote database. The database can't be accessed locally, it's an Azure WebApp, so i can't load the SQL statements on the server.
I was wondering if there is a way to speed up things, as the process has been really slow, like 4500 rows in 25 minutes, which feels really like I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using

```
 mysql -uxxxx -pxxxx -hremoteapp-on-azure azure_db < .\wp_term_relationships.sql
```

to load and the sql file is

```
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('2', '2', 'link_category', '', '0', '8');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('3', '3', 'post_tag', '', '0', '21');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('4', '4', 'post_tag', '', '0', '1423');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('5', '5', 'post_tag', '', '0', '21');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('6', '6', 'post_tag', '', '0', '106');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('16', '16', 'post_tag', '', '0', '41');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('18', '18', 'post_tag', '', '0', '154');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('20', '20', 'post_tag', '', '0', '279');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('21', '21', 'post_tag', '', '0', '41');
INSERT INTO `wp_43_term_taxonomy` VALUES ('25', '25', 'post_tag', '', '0', '429');
```

I've read about [optimizing for INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977898/mysql-optimizing-insert-speed-being-slowed-down-because-of-indices), but in this case the query feel really slow. On my local machine the whole insert is taking 20 seconds, or less, not 20 minutes.

Should i somehow use [multiple statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) to avoid round trips?i could stream the file in PHP and submit it in 1000 INSERT chunks

EDIT - To be clear, I need to be sure i optimized everything I can optimize from my side as I have no control on the server

Answer (score 1):

Since  most mysql versions turn on autocommit, use a transaction to have the server sync data to disk only once and not on every row.

Add at the top of your .sql:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

and append at the end:

```
COMMIT;
```

This will have the added advantage that either all will be inserted or none at all. Same for your php script. Or you may add begin/commit every say 50000 rows to commit in batches.

Answer (score 1):

Build INSERT statements will up to 1000 rows each.  Execute them in auto_commit=ON mode.

The former cuts down on round trips, plus other overhead in executing statements.  The latter avoids sending BEGIN/COMMIT.  Waiting for a million rows before committing, would slow things by building a huge "undo" log, then having to flush it.